# Why PhpStorm 2019.3 is enforcing me to use static closures instead of non-static in Route::get() Laravel

Tags: php, routes, closures, phpstorm, inspection

I used to code in Laravel, and I'm pretty good with it.

I've moved from **VSCode** to **PhpStorm 2019.3**, and it is enforcing me like it has intentions inside for language features, it gives me a *little warning message* that you should declare this closure method as static.

I know PhpStorm2019.3 fully supports **PHP 7.4**. So, the question is this, that should I always create closures functions as static like

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('posts', [
        'posts' => Post::all()
    ]);
});

// without static closure
Route::get('/posts/{post}', function (Post $post) {
    return view('post', [
        'post' => $post
    ]);
});

// with static closure
Route::get('/posts/{post}', static function (Post $post) {
    return view('post', [
        'post' => $post
    ]);
});
```

and is it good practice or bad practice? Because I found PhpStorm the best IDE in the world for PHP and Laravel developers.

Comment: 1) Please show the screenshot of the message with such a warning. A full message. Because I believe that this inspection comes from one of the custom plugins and not directly from PhpStorm core itself. 2) Yes, using `static` here makes sense, a better performance/memory usage in PHP (although since it's not defined inside the class it may not make a big difference here). **P.S.** Use Google Translate if you want to know a bit more about that: https://habr.com/ru/post/561550/ **P.P.S** Latest PhpStorm version is 2021.3

Comment: @LazyOne, yes i have added two custom plugins Laravel and laravel_idea, and i can't post the screenshot with the current stackoverflow reputation, and yes it also shows me that it will be memory efficient and will have better performance. Should i add static everytime whenever i add a route??